# Solution for sending html email from cronjobs

Tags: unix

I am looking for a way to email the output from various cronjob to specific addresses. The cronjob MAILTO command is too generic. I therefore pipe the output of a job into the mail command.

This works fine except that the output is html encoded and I need to add an Content-Type header to each message.

My version of mail doesn't support the -a flag, which would be perfect. Additionally it seems sendmail isn't available as this is running in a chrooted jail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution works as needed.

echo "**HTML Message goes here**" | mail -s "$(echo -e "This is the subject\nContent-Type: text/html")"

from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591755/how-send-html-mail-using-linux-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it to shell script like this

```
(echo "Content-type: text/html" ; cat ) | mail recipient
```

Comment: This solution - in itself correct - seems to prepend the header as part of the content. Piping this into sendmail does result in the desired result.

Comment: So, is your problem solved?

Comment: sorry, no. as i get the header as part of the body

Answer (score 0):

This works on Solaris 10 !

1) Be sure your system has a SMTP Server defined on the /etc/hosts

```
##############################################
#               SMTP SERVER                  #
##############################################
10.100.231.115    smtpserver.yourdomain.com
```

2) On the home directory of the user that owns the cron job, create the file:   .forward

3) Insert on the file  .forward   the email address to whom you desire to send the output of the cron Job.

*Please Note that I dont think this output is on HTML format !   Just give it a try !*